# rtl switching in joomla doesn't reposition the logo

Tags: css, joomla2.5

after adding RTL language to english in joomla website the logo is still LTR when i switching languages. am using protostar template how can i change the logo position in order to be RTL in the RTL language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for example:
HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
     <div class="header">
          <div class="logo <?php echo $this->direction;?>"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="content">
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
.header .logo{
     background: url('logo-ltr.png') no-repeat;
}
.header .logo.ltr{
     background: url('logo-ltr.png') no-repeat;
     float: left; //if necessary
}
.header .logo.rtr{
     background: url('logo-rtl.png') no-repeat;
     float: right; //if necessary
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've added
 :lang(ar){
  background-position:right center;
} and it works except in IE